# Manipulate Javascript rendered webform with ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've written a webform which is generated with javascript. I wanted to try automated testing using selenium in visual studio. All the samples I've seen which relate to javascript rendered HTML are looking to simply get the source. I would like to fill a form from it. When I run this currently, it can't find those ID's because I assume FindElement is searching through the original HTML rather than the version modified with javascript.

```
driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8080");
var source = driverGC.PageSource;

//Get rendered pagesource
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driverGC as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML");

driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys("alex@aol.com");
driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("agree")).Click();
```

Comment: Can you please share the javascript that modifies the page and the HTML (before and after modification if relevant) in Fiddler or something? Maybe it is a timing issue or something like that. In that case you would have to make the chromedriver wait for certain HTML to appear before continuing.

Comment: are you sure that the javascript does not open a popup or iframe? If that is the case, you should search in there by switching to it.